# i am not able to send data throught axios

Tags: node.js, axios

Not able to get data through axios .
below is the front end code

```js
function sendData(newData) {
    axios.post("/cart/addData",newData).then((res) => {
        alert(res)
    });
}

let getBtn = document.getElementById("cartButton")
getBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let data = getBtn.dataset.cart;
    let newData = JSON.parse(data);
    sendData(newData);
});
```

when I try to get it on server side it always shows req.body to be an empty object

```js
router.post("/addData", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req)   
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a middleware at the backend to parse the body:

`app.use(express.json());`